# Is my modification in queue.h implemented by Berkeley right

Tags: c, linux, data-structures, queue

the [queue.h](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sys/sys/queue.h?rev=1.30) implemented by Berkeley in their FreeBSD is very useful indeed, now i got a question about the **TAILQ_LAST** macro, please note the difference i present

**original code**

```
#define    TAILQ_HEAD(name, type)                        \
struct name 
{                                \
    struct type *tqh_first;    /* first element */            \
    struct type **tqh_last;    /* addr of last next element */        \
}

#define    TAILQ_ENTRY(type)                        \
struct 
{                                \
   struct type *tqe_next;    /* next element */            \
   struct type **tqe_prev;    /* address of previous next element */    \
}

#define    TAILQ_LAST(head, headname)                    \
(*(((struct headname *)((head)->tqh_last))->tqh_last))
```

**my proposal**

```
#define    TAILQ_LAST(head, headname)                    \
((head)->tqh_last))
```

my point is that the **tqh_last** member of *headname* refers to the address of the **tqe_next** member of the last **TAILQ_ENTRY**, which is exactly the address of the last entry in the tailq.

please correct me if i am wrong. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the two definitions, I'd think that

```
#define    TAILQ_LAST(head, headname)                    \
(*(((struct headname *)((head)->tqh_last))->tqh_last))
```

will return a `type*` whereas this

```
#define    TAILQ_LAST(head, headname)                    \
((head)->tqh_last))
```

will return a `type**`, so both are not equivalent.

Comment: for the original code, (head)->tqh_last) gives the addr of the last entry in the queue, then casted to (struct headname *), since the memory layout of TAILQ_ENTRY and TAILQ_HEAD is identical,

later, (((struct headname *)((head)->tqh_last))->tqh_last) is equivalent to accessing the tqe_prev member of last entry

finally, the code de-references that second-level pointer to get the addr of the last entry, isn't that tedious?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not same. please note that tqh_last is addr of last **next** element, not last element.
If you directly use `(head)->tqh_last`, then it simply returns NULL.

Then why it is `*(((struct headname *)((head)->tqh_last))->tqh_last)`

Please look at:

```
    #define TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(head, elm, field) do {            \
    TAILQ_NEXT((elm), field) = NULL;                \
    (elm)->field.tqe_prev = (head)->tqh_last;           \
    *(head)->tqh_last = (elm);                  \
    (head)->tqh_last = &TAILQ_NEXT((elm), field);           \
} while (0)
```

`(head)->tqh_last = &TAILQ_NEXT((elm), field);`
and what we need is `&TAILQ_NEXT((elm), field)->field.tqe_prev`, according to `(elm)->field.tqe_prev = (head)->tqh_last;`, then we get 
`(*(((struct headname *)((head)->tqh_last))->tqh_last))`